# CosmosDB: Minimum throughput does not make sense

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

we got a cosmos DB containing 24 containers as of now.
The throughput is provisioned on database Level.

I would expect the Minimum throughput to be 2400 RUs but actually 4500 is expected. (Shown in Azure Portal as well as an error message in .NET SDK)

> Expectation:
>
> **Count of containers * 100 RU/s = Min. RU/s**
>
> or if container count is less or equal to four
>
> **400 RU/s**

[image: screenshot of RU count]

I observed the behaviour, that after I delete the database and recreate it, the throughput works as expected.
This behaviour only occurs after some days working with the database.

> Is there an explanation why this is expected or is this a bug in
> CosmosDB itself?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you want to shrink your Cosmos DB throughput ?

Comment: Yes thats what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You have two regions configured, per your screenshot:

[image: two regions]

Each region is consuming the 2400 or so RUs. 2x2400 = 4800. Seems like you have slightly less than 2400 RU per region.

In any case: the two-region setup is what's costing you double the expected RU.

Comment: This is actually incorrect. The calculation there shows you have 2 regions with 4500 RUs (each) for a total of 17.298 daily.

Comment: I dont think this is correct. If I reduce the count of collections to for example two collections, even then the minimum required throughput won´t shrink. I need to mention, that after I delete the whole database and recreate it, the throughput works as expected.

Comment: RU won't shrink, once expanded past a certain point (due to allocated partitions). You often cannot shrink back to absolute minimum. But in your example, it clearly shows you have two regions (and each region multiplies your RU cost).

Comment: @AlexDrenea - I don't understand your comment. There is no such thing as a "daily" RU cost. RU (request units) are measured *per second*. You purchase "RU/Second". If you have 4500 RU, that is "4500 RU/Second." Not per day, not per month. The OP mentioned expecting ~2400 RU but saw double that (and they have two regions). Perhaps the OP misspoke, and actually has 4500 RU (which in turn would be 9000 RU, with two regions). Hard to tell from the original post.

Comment: @DavidMakogon - To clarify the regions topic: We only have one "write" region. As per the documentation this would lead to the my expected behaviour. If the Cosmos account is configured with a single write region, the total RUs available globally on the container (database) = R x N.

Comment: @AlexDrenea - ah - you were talking about daily *cost*, not daily *RU* (I need more coffee). Yep - you're right. 4500x2=9000RU. Which is approx. $18/day of overall cost

Comment: I think your explanation with allocated partitions makes more sense. I would edit the answer too so it's not confusing to others who won't read the comments